Not able to add azure microsoft entra Id group to azure devops organization
Not able to add azure microsoft entra Id group to azure devops organization.
We are trying to add group and users from azure microsoft entra Id to Azure devops organization but when we are trying to in azure devops it did not display the group name. Entra ID group is having both user and service principal. Can some one please help me here to add.
Thanks in advance
We are trying to add group and users from azure microsoft entra Id to Azure devops organization but when we are trying to in azure devops it did not display the group name. Entra ID group is having both user and service principal. Can some one please help me here to add.

You need to make sure DevOps organization is connected to correct Microsoft Entra ID, and your account grant correct permission. You can add the azure microsoft entra group to exiting group following the doc above, or add from group rule. Please check the answer below, let me know if you have any queries.

Please review the pre-requisites, pay attention to the required permissions. You have to check that you have required permissions in both Azure DevOps and Entra AAD group
Azure DevOps -

You must be a member of the Project Collection Administrators group or the organization Owner to make the connection.

Azure Entra AAD -

Ensure that you exist in Microsoft Entra ID as a member. For more information, see how you can convert a Microsoft Entra ID guest into a member.

Then Connect your organization to Microsoft Entra ID
Make sure you are in the correct directory/tenant of Azure DevOps  and Azure Entra ID. Selecting the correct tenant is crucial for successful connection.

Different with common user, you cannot add azure microsoft entra group from DevOps organization settings -> Users page.
Please follow the prerequisite instructions, make sure the DevOps is connected to correct Microsoft Entra ID, and your account grant correct permission. So that it can find the group from Microsoft Entra from DevOps.

You can add the azure microsoft entra group to exiting group following the doc above, or add from group rule.
